# Getting 500 - Internal server error in Azure Website after restart

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a web application in azure(App Service), recently i have restarted the app, after restaring i am getting:

> 500 - Internal server error.
>
> There is a problem with the resource you
> are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

Please let me know what could be the issue. application was working fine till that time. I didnt change any other settings.
How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Any further details? If only have this error, it will be hard to find out where is wrong because this error is a common error..

Answer (score 2):

Go to the app service, then pick Monitoring -> App Service Logs. Then enable Application Logging (FileSystem) and save the changes. Now go into Monitoring -> Log Stream and watch the Application Logs while the site is starting up, this will most likely give the detailed error message.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you can do step by step

**Step 1:** Use the KUDU console at https://sitename.scm.azurewebsites.net. Check if there are errors. More info about [`KUDU`](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki)

**Step 2:** Have you turned on the detailed error message in the Diagnostics logs tab of the Azure portal. If not enable and see if you can track any error.This will give you a .zip file. Browse to LogFiles->DetailedErrors and here you should see some error pages.

**Step 3:** You can add [`Application Insights`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/monitor/) to your application and log those errors when you start the application

If nothing works, try restarting app service, or access it from a different location (because it happened to me earlier)

Comment: I dont have permission for  KUDU console. Have checked APP Insights and didnt find any log. Also tried restarting app service but no luck.